# Implement own ActionListener in JSF

Tags: dynamic, jsf-2, richfaces, actionlistener

How can I implement my own ActionListener in JSF.

I require it to attach this action listener to dynamic component which I am building..

I am trying to use MethodExpression like this:-

```
HtmlCommandLink link = new HtmlCommandLink();
        link.setId("linkId");
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        MethodExpression methodExpression = context.getApplication().getExpressionFactory().createMethodExpression(
            context.getELContext(), "#{bean.actionListener}", null, new Class[] { ActionEvent.class });
link.addActionListener(new MethodExpressionActionListener(methodExpression));
```

However is there any other way to attach a custom actionListener to a dynamically generated component.Also what exactly is the use of MethodExpression in this context.

One point is that `addActionListener` take `MethodExpressionActionListener` as the argument and we need to specify methodExpression object in that..

But what can be the real functionality behind this..I went through the javadoc of MethodExpression but I found it not to be of much use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of the argument of `addActionListener` is [ActionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/api/javax/faces/event/ActionListener.html). Use this instead of MethodExpressionActionListener, it is an interface with a single method:

```
public void processAction(ActionEvent event) throws AbortProcessingException;
```

(MethodExpressionActionListener implements this interface)

Comment: So what you imply to say is I create a class say CheckList implements ActionListener.It will have prcoessAction method inside it. Now what should I write inside the processAction method.I mean the entire business functionality when ActionListener is fired is written in my bean under the actionListener method. So I shoudl leave this blank.???  ..Next question...link.addActionListener(new CheckList()) is correct or it needs any other modification????